# C# - Override eventargs of WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler

Tags: c#, event-handling, browser, overriding, eventargs

I would like to override the `EventArgs` of the event `WebBrowserDocumentCompleted`. I can't create a personal event handler, because I have no idea when I should fire the event `DocumentDownloadCompleted`. The data I would like to add to the `EventArgs` is the `OriginalPageLink`.

I'm trying to download a page, but I'm redirected to a login page (only once). I've setup a way to login, but then I would like to re-try navigating to the original page, but I don't have it any more. I could set a global variable to track each time that link, but, is there a way to edit `EventArgs`? Do I need to also modify `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler`.

My code looks like

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;           
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(OriginalPageLink);
}

private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.ToString().Contains("login.smlogin.ibb.ubs.net")) {
        loginWithWEBSSO(webBrowser1);
        webBrowser1.Navigate(***e.OriginalPageLink***);
    } else { 
        string mybody = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Marco

Comment: This cannot work, the WebBrowser control creates the instance of the class.  It doesn't know anything about your customizations.  Don't use a global variable, a private field in your class works fine.  Or a lambda, even better.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to latch onto the [`WebBrowser.Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event to keep track of the navigation history using some sort of collection. Go back to the previous page before the login occurs. The `Navigate` event will trigger the Navigating and remove the previous URL, so you need to manage a collection or just limit which items get managed in your state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private string for this, but I'm thinking you have to rework this. So far I see this sequence:

```
1. Navigate to Original page.
2. Presented with login page.
3. Fill in the username / password and then submit.
4. Navigate to Original page.
5. Step 3's process fires a DocumentCompleted event - URL still "login" (loop).
6. Step 4's process fires a DocumentCompleted.
```

The timing of the steps is not guaranteed so step 4 might prompt you for a login again.

I worked around this by always going to the login page first and logging in. Once that fires a DocumentCompleted I would then go to the original page.  I kept track of all of this using private variables. The simplest would be "private int _step=1;" Then deciding what to do in DocumentCompleted based on which step you were on.